# Match a Sequence to a bigger Sequence

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, constrained-optimization

I am trying to solve the following problem:
Say I have a small sequence $\sigma = (σ_{1}, σ_{2}, ..., σ_{i}, ..., σ_{N})$ and a larger $\hat{\sigma} = (\hat{σ}_{1}, \hat{σ}_{2}, ..., \hat{σ}_{j}, ..., \hat{σ}_{M})$ with $M > N$ and a non-negative cost function $C[N, M]$ between each element in $\sigma$ and each element in $\hat{\sigma}$. I am trying to find an optimal alignment of the first sequence inside the second:
$$\operatorname{argmax}_{S} \sum_{(i, j) \in S} C[i, j] \\ \operatorname{s.t.} \quad \quad S = \{(i_{1}, j_{1}) <\; ...\; <(i_{k}, j_{k}) <\;...\; < (i_{N}, j_{N})\;|\; \forall k\;\; 1 \leq i_{k} \leq N  \wedge 1\leq j_{k}\leq M \}   $$

I assume this problem has a difficulty between convex optimization and combinatorial optimization (due to the ordering).
Does anybody recognize this problem as a well studied one and have an algorithm or a solver to propose (even for approximate solutions)?

Comment: There's something strange about your notation: it implies the $\sigma_i$ and $\hat\sigma_i$ play no role in the problem, because *everything* depends only on the indexes.  If that's what you intended, the solution is trivial: just match all indexes.  But I suspect you didn't mean that.  It would be nice if you could use a clearer notation to express what you mean.  Incidentally, it is reminiscent of a problem solved by ["dynamic time warping" (DTW).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)

Comment: You shouldn't care about the sequence as soon as you have the cost function.
What do you mean "match all the indexes"? Will this be optimal?

Comment: It is similar indeed to DTW and thank you for pointing it out, but without the constraints used by DTW. For example, in my case all pairs are unique and strictly increasing.

Comment: I don't understand how a function could reasonably be called a "cost function" when it doesn't depend on the values of the sequence (nor even why you even mention the values at all).  Could you explain what application this is intended to have?

Comment: To downvote something, that someone "doesn't understand its use", is a toxic behavior.

Comment: The cost function has been calculated according to the sequences, but after it's calculation, we don't care any more about the sequences.

Comment: That's not what the current formulation of your question says.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem is that of sequence alignment.
A fine candidate seems to be the library: https://pypi.org/project/paired/

```
def align(cost):
    def scorer(i, j): return cost[j, i]
    m, n = cost.shape
    return paired.align(list(range(m)), list(range(n)), scorer=scorer)
```